# createAction вернуть тип(TS) для redux-saga

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-saga

Есть action

```
export const addRequest = createAction<string>(ADD_REQUEST);
```

Как из него вернуть тип для TS который потом можно передать в аргументы saga.

Попытка 1:

```
export type addRequest = typeof addRequest;

function* addWorker(action: addRequest) {
  console.log(action.payload)
}
```

Ошибка: *Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'ActionCreatorWithPayload<string, string>'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как же все просто оказалось. `export type addRequest = ReturnType<typeof addRequest>`.

Ответ нашелся тут https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype